# Unittest + Selenium - __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, inheritance, super

I'm working with unittest and selenium for the first time but thats also my first bigger code in python. I found some answers for this problem but there was no explaination for classes with __ init __ inheritance and method super().__ init __()

**TL;DR**
I have classes that inherits one by one. The first class StartInstance that creates chrome instance inherits from unittest.TestCase and the problem is with inheritance and super().**init**() in other classes, becouse when i remove it test normaly starts

All looks like:

```
class StartInstance(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls): pass

class A(StartInstance):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() adding variables etc to init

class B(A):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() adding variables etc to init

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() adding variables etc to init

class PrepareTests(B, C, D):
    def all tests(self):
        self.tests_B
        self.tests_C
        self.tests_D

 class Tests(PrepareTests):
    def test_click:
        click()
        all_tests()


 #and finally somewhere a test runner
 suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Tests)
 runner.run(suite())

#when i run this i get this error and it only raises when i 
add classes with their own init
#heh TL;DR almost as long as normal text sorry :(
```

---

**ALL:**

**FULL ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "xyz\main_test.py", line 24, 
 in <module>
   runner.run(suite())
  File "xyz\main_test.py", line 11, 
in suite
   about_us = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(AboutUs)
 File 
"xyz\Python36\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 92, in loadTestsFromTestCase
loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
 File "xyz\Python36\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 24, in __init__
  self.addTests(tests)
 File "xyz\Python36\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 57, in addTests
   for test in tests:
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Thats my code:

I have a settings.py file with variables in dict of dicts accessed by settings.xyz["layer1"]["KEY"]

**setup.py** - setup class for selenium

```
class StartInstance(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.driver.get(settings.URLS['MAIN_URL'])
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
```

**main_tests_config.py** - next layer - now very basic configs

```
class MainTestConfig(StartInstance):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.language = settings.TEST_LANGUAGE
        self.currency = settings.TEST_CURRENCY
```

**header.py** (got few more files like this) - next layer translates code from config.py to class variables, inherits from previous classes becouse it needs global language

```
class HeaderPath(MainTestConfig):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.logo_path = settings.PAGE_PATHS["HEADER"]["LOGO"]
        self.business_path = settings.PAGE_PATHS["HEADER"]["BUSINESS"]

class HeaderText(MainTestConfig):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.business_text = settings.PAGE_CONTENT[self.language]["HEADER"]["BUSINESS"]
        self.cart_text = settings.PAGE_CONTENT[self.language]["HEADER"]["CART"]
```

**header_tests.py** - next layer, inherits variables(HeadetText, HeaderPath, Urls(class Urls it is class with page urls variables)), language(from MainTestConfig), and selenium driver (from first class StartInstance), example build of class

```
class HeaderStaticTest(HeaderText, HeaderPath, Urls):
    def header_static(self):
        self.logo_display()
        self.method2()
        # etc..

    def logo_display(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.logo_path)
    def self.method2(self):
        pass
```

**static_display.py** - next layer, class that inherits all classes with tests like previous one and uses their methods that runs all tests but not as test_

```
class StaticDisplay(HeaderStaticTest, HorizontalStaticTest, VerticalStaticTest):
    def static_display(self):
        self.header_static()
        self.horizontal_static()
        self.vertical_static()
```

**test_about_us.py** - next layer, a normal unittest testcase it inherits only a previous one but in general it inherits all prevous classes that i wrote, now i can test all "static views" on page that dont change when i click on button

```
class AboutUs(StaticDisplay):
    def test_horizontal_menu_click(self):
        about_us_element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.hor_about_path)
        about_us_element.click()
        self.assertIn(
            self.about_url,
            self.driver.current_url
        )

    def test_check_static_after_horizontal(self):
        self.static_display()
```

(finally)
**main_cases.py** - runner with this error, and it only raises when I add classes with their own init... have no idea how to repair it... please help

```
def suite():
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    about_us = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(AboutUs)
    return unittest.TestSuite([about_us])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())
```

As i said there is somewhere problem with this new def __ init __ and super().__ init __() in new classes... where I'm making a mistake?

When i start this test case i get an error:

**TypeError: __ init __() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given** Full error message above, probably it is needed

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TestCase` instances take an optional keyword argument `methodName`; I'm guessing the `unittest` module passes this explicitly behind the scenes at some point. Typically when I'm subclassing classes I didn't make myself I'll use this pattern; this should fix your problem:

```
class SubClass(SupClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Especially when you're not passing any arguments to your `__init__` method, passing through the arguments in this manner is a good way to avoid the error you're getting. If you do want to pass something custom to your `__init__` method, you can do something like this:

```
class SubClass(SupClass):
    def __init__(self, myarg, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       # do something with your custom argument
```

Comment: Thanks for advice I have used this in my code, the problem was in other place I just posted solutions ;)

Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Did not fix my problem, however that is a really good advice!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem... It is something else than you wrote the solution that you wrote is good too and I also used It in my code.

Problem from my question was here:

```
suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Tests)
runner.run(suite())
```

I should change to:

```
something = Tests
suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(something)
runner.run(suite())
```

BUT another thing is that I had to rebuild it completly to work properly
At start: inheritance __ init __ from previous class with super was stupid becouse I didn't have acces to the class before... so I couldn't access my variables. So I've changed:

```
class SubClass(SupClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

with:

```
class SubClass(SupClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).setUpClass(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then I understood that __ init __ inheritance from unittest.TestCase is impossible. To imagine what happened...

My new way to start test cases:

```
something = Tests
```

it was creating a new error... that said i have to use **Tests()** but when I used this form I got and previous error so both ways was bad.
So I just created class with variables, but with no __ init __ and no super()

```
class Something(StartInstance):
    a = thing1
    b = thing2
    c = thing3
```

I'm writing this becouse maybe someone in future will try to use __ init __ with unittest... It doesn't work... or I just didn't find the solution, but I'm new :P